# What is wrong with this 2048 game code?(python)(tkinter)

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to show the gameboard and the score and get the directional keys as input using tkinter, but there are some errors with this code.

there's a problem in the tkinter part, but I don't know what is wrong with this code.

1. directional key input problem
   -> computer can't understand get_input(event)
2. tkinter board update problem
3. win.mainloop() placing problem

```
import random
from tkinter import *
key=0
win = Tk()
win.title("2048")
win.geometry("345x430")

label={}


def get_input(event):
    global key
    key = event.keysym
    if key == "Up":
        direction = 0
    if key == "Down":
        direction = 1
    if key == "Left":
        direction = 2
    if key == "Right":
        direction = 3

win.bind("<Key>", get_input)




board_size = 4
blank = 0
board = [[blank for _ in range(board_size)] for _ in range(board_size)]
new_board = [[blank for _ in range(board_size)] for _ in range(board_size)]
score = 0
ratio = 0.9


direction_move = [[1, 0], [-1, 0], [0, 1], [0, -1]]


def generate_number():
    tmp = random.random()
    if tmp<ratio:
        return 2
    return 4

def generate():
    candidate=[]
    for i in range(board_size):
        for j in range(board_size):
            if board[i][j] is blank:
                candidate.append([i,j])
    cor = random.choice(candidate)
    board[cor[0]][cor[1]] = generate_number()

def init_board():
    generate()
    generate()
    myscore1=Label(win, text="score")
    myscore1.grid(row=0 , column=2)


def print_board():
    for i in range(16):
        j=i//4
        k=i%4
        label[i] = Label(win, width=10, height=5, background='#d3d3d3', relief='ridge', text=str(board[j][k]))
        label[i].grid(row=j+1, column=k)
    score_show=Label(win, text=int(score))
    score_show.grid(row=0 , column=3)


win.mainloop()



def move_board(direction, update):
    global score
    if direction == 0:
        for j in range(board_size):
            for i in range(board_size):
                new_board[i][j] = board[i][j]
    if direction == 1:
        for i in range(board_size):
            for j in range(board_size):
                new_board[i][j] = board[board_size-1-i][board_size-1-j]
    if direction == 2:
        for i in range(board_size):
            for j in range(board_size):
                new_board[i][j] = board[board_size-1-j][i]
    if direction == 3:
        for j in range(board_size):
            for i in range(board_size):
                new_board[i][j] = board[j][board_size-1-i]
    tmp_board = [[blank for _ in range(board_size)] for _ in range(board_size)]
    tmp_score = 0
    for j in range(board_size):
        top = 0
        for i in range(board_size):
            if new_board[i][j] != blank:
                if tmp_board[top][j] == blank:
                    tmp_board[top][j] = new_board[i][j]
                elif new_board[i][j] == tmp_board[top][j]:
                    tmp_board[top][j] *= 2
                    top += 1
                    tmp_score += tmp_board[top-1][j]
                else:
                    top += 1
                    tmp_board[top][j] = new_board[i][j]
    if update:
        score += tmp_score
        if direction == 0:
            for j in range(board_size):
                for i in range(board_size):
                    board[i][j] = tmp_board[i][j]
        if direction == 1:
            for j in range(board_size):
                for i in range(board_size):
                    board[i][j] = tmp_board[board_size-1-i][board_size-1-j]
        if direction == 3:
            for j in range(board_size):
                for i in range(board_size):
                    board[i][j] = tmp_board[board_size-1-j][i]
        if direction == 2:
            for j in range(board_size):
                for i in range(board_size):
                    board[i][j] = tmp_board[j][board_size-1-i]
    for i in range(board_size):
        for j in range(board_size):
            if tmp_board[i][j] is not new_board[i][j]:
                return True
    return False


def next_turn():
    empty_check = False
    for i in range(board_size):
        for j in range(board_size):
            if board[i][j]==blank:
                empty_check = True
    if not empty_check:
        for i in range(4):
            move_board(i)

def game_over():
    for i in range(4):
        if move_board(i,False):
            return False
    return True

if __name__ == '__main__':
    init_board()
    print_board()
    while not game_over():
        get_input(event)
        generate()
        print_board()
    print("Your score is " + str(score))
```

please tell me what part is wrong or fix this code for me. thank you.

Comment: What are you trying to make? Can you please tell us?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2048_(video_game)

Comment: did you try to move all the functions to the top and the `win.mainloop` to the bottom

Comment: yes, but moving the functions can't solve problem 1, 2.

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: you have to describe problems. We can't read in your mind. And don't expect that we will run code to see problems.

Comment: at this moment I see one big problem - you have two loops `mainloop()` and some loop `while not game_over():` but GUI should use only one loop and it should be `mainloop()`. And this can be you main problem. Code runs only `mainloop()` and `get_events` works (and `print(key)` ) but `mainloop()` blocks other loop which you created to move obejct - so `key` is never used. You will have to rewrite it in different way. Maybe using `win.after(milliseconds, my_loop)` instead of `while`

Comment: other problem - you bind `get_input` to `<Key>` - and this is OK - but later you try to run it as normal function - and this is wrong and useless. Normal function can't get `event` with pressed key. Only first method can get event - `mainloop` runs all time and check if there is new key/mouse event from system and then it runs `get_input()` with this `event`. Normally you can't get `event`.

Comment: in `print_board()` you create labels - and you run it in loop so you create new labels in the same place - and and this in wrong. Tkinter will not remove previous labels so you will have many unused labels in memory. You should create labels only once at start and later you should use `label["text"] = "new string"` to replace text in label.

Comment: Thank you for explaining! I really appreciate your help. Have a nice day~

Answer (score 0):

Working code with many changes so it is hard to describe it.

I uses `after(250, game_loop)` instead of `while`-loop to execute function `game_loop` every 250ms (0.25s) and this function checks if key was pressed and then it moves numbers and update text in labels.
And this way I don't block `mainloop` - and it can runs all need code.

I think it could be done in different way. It could use `get_input` to run code only when key was pressed.

```
import random
import tkinter as tk  # PEP8: `import *` is not preferred
import time

# --- functions ---   # PEP8: all functions directly after `import`

def generate_number():
    tmp = random.random()
    if tmp < ratio:
        return 2
    return 4

def generate():    
    candidate = []    
    for row in range(board_size):
        for col in range(board_size):
            if board[row][col] is blank:
                candidate.append([row,col])
                
    row, col = random.choice(candidate)
    board[row][col] = generate_number()

def create_board(win):
    global score_show
    
    for i in range(16):
        row = i//4
        col = i%4
        label[i] = tk.Label(win, width=10, height=5, background='#d3d3d3', relief='ridge')
        label[i].grid(row=row+1, column=col)

    tk.Label(win, text="Score").grid(row=0 , column=2)
        
    score_show = tk.Label(win, text=score)
    score_show.grid(row=0 , column=3)

def update_board():
    for i in range(16):
        row = i//4
        col = i%4
        text = board[row][col]
        if text == 0:
            text = ''
        label[i]["text"] = text

    score_show["text"] = score

def move_board(direction, update=False):
    global score

    if direction == 0:
        for j in range(board_size):
            for i in range(board_size):
                new_board[i][j] = board[i][j]
                
    if direction == 1:
        for i in range(board_size):
            for j in range(board_size):
                new_board[i][j] = board[board_size-1-i][board_size-1-j]
                
    if direction == 2:
        for i in range(board_size):
            for j in range(board_size):
                new_board[i][j] = board[board_size-1-j][i]
                
    if direction == 3:
        for j in range(board_size):
            for i in range(board_size):
                new_board[i][j] = board[j][board_size-1-i]
                
    tmp_board = [[blank for _ in range(board_size)] for _ in range(board_size)]
    tmp_score = 0
    
    for j in range(board_size):
        top = 0
        for i in range(board_size):
            if new_board[i][j] != blank:
                if tmp_board[top][j] == blank:
                    tmp_board[top][j] = new_board[i][j]
                elif new_board[i][j] == tmp_board[top][j]:
                    tmp_board[top][j] *= 2
                    top += 1
                    tmp_score += tmp_board[top-1][j]
                else:
                    top += 1
                    tmp_board[top][j] = new_board[i][j]
                    
    if update:
        score += tmp_score
        if direction == 0:
            for j in range(board_size):
                for i in range(board_size):
                    board[i][j] = tmp_board[i][j]
        if direction == 1:
            for j in range(board_size):
                for i in range(board_size):
                    board[i][j] = tmp_board[board_size-1-i][board_size-1-j]
        if direction == 3:
            for j in range(board_size):
                for i in range(board_size):
                    board[i][j] = tmp_board[board_size-1-j][i]
        if direction == 2:
            for j in range(board_size):
                for i in range(board_size):
                    board[i][j] = tmp_board[j][board_size-1-i]
                    
    for i in range(board_size):
        for j in range(board_size):
            if tmp_board[i][j] is not new_board[i][j]:
                return True
            
    return False


def next_turn():
    empty_check = False
                         
    for row in range(board_size):
        for col in range(board_size):
            if board[row][col] == blank:
                empty_check = True
                         
    if not empty_check:
        for direct in range(4):
            move_board(direct)

def game_over():
    for direct in range(4):
        if move_board(direct, False):
            return False
    return True

def get_input(event):
    global direction
    
    key = event.keysym
    print('key:', key)
    
    if key == "Up":
        direction = 0
    if key == "Down":
        direction = 1
    if key == "Left":
        direction = 2
    if key == "Right":
        direction = 3
    
def game_loop():
    global direction
    
    if game_over():
        win.destroy()   # close window
    else:        
        if direction is not None:        # run code only when key was pressed
            move_board(direction, True)  # make move
            generate()                   # create new number
            update_board()               # change text in esxisting labels 
            direction = None             # clear direction
        win.after(250, game_loop)        # run again after 250ms (0.25s) 
        
# - variables -

direction = None
label = {}

board_size = 4
blank = 0
board     = [[blank for _ in range(board_size)] for _ in range(board_size)]
new_board = [[blank for _ in range(board_size)] for _ in range(board_size)]
score = 0
ratio = 0.9

direction_move = [[1, 0], [-1, 0], [0, 1], [0, -1]]

# - main -

if __name__ == '__main__':
    
    win = tk.Tk()
    win.title("2048")
    win.geometry("345x430")
    
    win.bind("<Key>", get_input)  

    create_board(win)  # only create Labels
    
    generate()         # generate first number as start
    generate()         # generate second number as start
    
    update_board()     # change text in esxisting labels 
    
    game_loop()        # start game loop 
    
    win.mainloop()     # run main loop which will run it all
    
    print("Your score is", score)
```

[PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

Comment: Wow... I don't know how to thank you... Thank you so much! I really appreciate your help. Have a nice day!

Comment: I change little code - I removed global `key` and use global `direction` for this.